# MySQL - Joins and Count

Tags: mysql, join, count

I'm working with two separate tables:

> persons(person_id, first_name, last_name, gender, birth_date, street, town, county)

> likes(person_id, food)

The primary key is person_id in both, where your ID in 'persons' (giving your personal details) match up with an ID in 'likes' which lists pairs of IDs and foods that person enjoys.

The question I've been asked is

> List for each county and each food the number of individuals in that county that like that food.

So far I have got

```
SELECT p.county, l.food
FROM persons AS p
    JOIN likes AS l
    ON p.person_id = l.person_id;
```

This gives pairs like (Cork, Nutella) and (Limerick, Chocolate) however I'm not sure how to add the count column in to remove duplicates to show how many times the county and food combinations show up (ie. Cork, Nutella, 2 or Limerick, Chocolate, 3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just need to group by the country and food.

```
SELECT p.county,
       l.food,
       count(*)
       FROM persons p
            INNER JOIN likes l
                       ON p.person_id = l.person_id
       GROUP BY p.county,
                l.food;
```

Comment: That works absolutely perfectly, I had even tried count(*) and group by p.county earlier. I was so close, thanks a million!